# This function makes the .exe crash, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, c, crash, codeblocks

I have 2 structures: **medic** and **patient**. I have to read data from 2 different .txt docs and then show it in the console.
I'm using CodeBlocks. When I tried to debug this, I found out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJZFh.png) happens right after **citireM** is executed. I asked my teacher about it and did some googling but to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct date
{
    int d,m,y;
};
struct medic
{
    int cod;
    char name[50],specs[50];
};
struct patient
{
    int cod;
    date bd;
    char name[50],adress[50];
};
struct consultatie
{
    int codp,codm;
    date dc;
    char diag[100];
};
void citireM(medic M[], int &n)
{
    int i; char * p; char l[50];
    ifstream f("medics.txt");
    f>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        strcpy(l,"");
        f>>M[i].cod;
        f.getline(l,50);
        p=strtok(l,";");
        strcpy(M[i].name,p);
        p=strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(M[i].specs,p);
    }
}
void citireP(patient P[], int &n)
{
    char * p; char l[50];
    ifstream ff("patients.txt");
    ff>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ff>>P[i].cod;
        strcpy(l,"");
        ff.getline(l,50);
        p=strtok(l,";");
        strcpy(P[i].name,p);
        p=strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(P[i].adress,p);
        ff>>P[i].bd.d>>P[i].bd.m>>P[i].bd.y;
    }
}
void printM(medic M[], int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<M[i].cod<<" "<<M[i].name<<" "<<M[i].specs;
}
void printP(patient P[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<P[i].cod<<" "<<P[i].name<<" "<<P[i].adress<<" "<<P[i].bd.d<<"/"<<P[i].bd.m<<"/"<<P[i].bd.y;
}
int main()
{
    medic m[30];
    patient p[300];
    int nm,np;
    citireM(m,nm);
    citireP(p,np);
    printM(m,nm);
    printP(p,np);
    return 0;
}
```

**medics.txt**

```
    3
    007 J.J. Jouleau; medic stomatolog;
    32 Michael Bush; medic chirurg;
    88 Ceva Nume Lung Aici; medic neidentificat;
```

**patients.txt**

```
    2
    321 Insert Name Here; Timisoara, judetul Timis; 2 5 1991
    123 Insert Some Other Name Here; Nu se stie unde traieste; 1 6 1654
```

Comment: Check what is in `l`, and make sure that `p` is not `NULL` before passing it to `strcpy()`.

Comment: This crash should mean you wrote past the end of a local array.  The only local array that makes sense for that is `l` and I can't see any way you could write past the end of it.  I see no defense against writing past the end of `m`.  That shouldn't exactly fit the symptoms, but you should have some defense against it anyway, and it might somehow be the bug you're chasing.

Comment: A more basic issue is that C strings are the biggest source of beginner errors in C and are a generally rotten approximation of true strings.  You tagged your question C++, not C (and use a C++ stream).  So why do you use C strings and C arrays where std::string and std::vector make so much more sense?

Comment: You should post up your txt files as well.

Comment: [medics.txt](http://pastebin.com/Vqedy6Z8) and [patients.txt](http://pastebin.com/FFeqKB94)

@JSF I use these because my school requires me to use these. I personally prefer std::string as I find it easier to use.

Comment: @David Please Those 2 files are important, but they are on an external site and the link can only be found in comments. Both these things should be changed. Please edit your question and add the content of those 2 files to the question body.

Comment: @FabioTurati there. I don't know why I was forced to add them as code, though.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:c]?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to keep your function to as close to the same as your.  There are much cleaner ways to do this though.  This also does not take into account errors with your input files, but I just wanted to get you on the right track.

```
int char_to_int(char* src)
{
    int res = 0;
    for(int i = 0; src[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        res = res * 10 + src[i] - '0';
    }
    return res;
}

void citireP(patient P[], int &n)
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
    char* p; char l[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char* date;
    ifstream ff("patients.txt",ios_base::skipws);
    ff >> n;
    char input[3][BUFFER_SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        ff >> P[i].cod;
        strcpy(l, "");
        ff.getline(l,BUFFER_SIZE);
        p = strtok(l, ";");
        strcpy(P[i].name, p);
        p = strtok(NULL, ";");
        strcpy(P[i].adress, p);
        p = strtok(NULL, ";");
        date = strtok(p, " ");
        P[i].bd.d = char_to_int(date);
        date = strtok(NULL, " ");
        P[i].bd.m = char_to_int(date);
        date = strtok(NULL, " ");
        P[i].bd.y = char_to_int(date);
    }
}
```

edit...

I just wrote a atoi type function for you so you dont have include extra things in your project.

Comment: *You already read the line in now you are trying to read what comes next into the date variable.*  
  


Well this basically means I have to completely change my idea.
And yes, this is a homework assignment that I've been struggling with for almost a week. I just don't know how to input the whole medic/patient's name (or any other char/string with unknown length and separated by space) from the txt.

Comment: @David Are you required to use getline?

Comment: No, I'm just required to use string.h. Using getline and separating data via strtok was my idea.

Comment: Do you just want the answer or would like me to help you get the answer since this is homework?

Comment: Both are fine with me. Whichever kills less of your time.

Comment: give me a sec i will post up a complete answer for you.

Comment: So, according to the internet, ios_base::skipws *disables skipping of leading whitespace by the formatted input functions*, which I found really useful even though I don't know how to use it yet.  
But what about **atoi**? I don't see you declaring it anywhere so I suppose it's some function.  

Also, it gives me [this](http://i.imgur.com/EtCLUuC.png)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/  atoi .its just a standard function that turns a char into an int.